# Injecting UserService into SecurityConfiguration in jhipster leads to spring bean circular dependency

Tags: java, spring, jhipster, auth0

I'm trying to configure a jhipster 4 application to use auth0 for auth. When I initially generated the project I selected the JWT options, which seems to work fine and provide JWT support. What I am now trying to do is handle integration with auth0 correctly, by reading their provided JWT tokens and creating a user when a new auth0 username is seen for the first time.

To do this, I planned to inject the `UserService` into the jhipster provided `JWTFilter` and create a new account when seeing a username for the first time as such:

```
private UserService userService;

public JWTFilter(TokenProvider tokenProvider, UserRepository userRepository, UserService userService) {
    this.tokenProvider = tokenProvider;
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
    this.userService = userService;
}
```

In order to do this I have to add `UserService` to the constructor of `JWTConfigurer` and configure the `JWTFilter` as such:

```
package com.proj.security.jwt;

import com.proj.repository.UserRepository;
import com.proj.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.SecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

public class JWTConfigurer extends SecurityConfigurerAdapter<DefaultSecurityFilterChain, HttpSecurity> {

    public static final String AUTHORIZATION_HEADER = "Authorization";

    public static final String AUTHORIZATION_TOKEN = "access_token";

    private TokenProvider tokenProvider;

    private UserRepository userRepository;

    private UserService userService;

    public JWTConfigurer(TokenProvider tokenProvider, UserRepository userRepository, UserService userService) {
        this.tokenProvider = tokenProvider;
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        JWTFilter customFilter = new JWTFilter(tokenProvider, userRepository, userService);
        http.addFilterBefore(customFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

Finally, this has to be injected into the constructor of `SecurityConfiguration`

```
public SecurityConfiguration(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder, UserDetailsService userDetailsService,
        TokenProvider tokenProvider, CorsFilter corsFilter, UserRepository userRepository, UserService userService) {

    this.authenticationManagerBuilder = authenticationManagerBuilder;
    this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    this.tokenProvider = tokenProvider;
    this.corsFilter = corsFilter;
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
    this.userService = userService;
}
```

and added to the `JWTConfigurer` bean

```
private JWTConfigurer securityConfigurerAdapter() {
    return new JWTConfigurer(tokenProvider, userRepository, userService);
}
```

However, when I start up the application with maven I am given the following errors:

```
2017-03-13 22:41:00.816  WARN 45420 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Error handling failed (Error creating bean with name 'delegatingApplicationListener' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cache.annotation.ProxyCachingConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importRegistry' available)
2017-03-13 22:41:00.823 ERROR 45420 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

┌─────┐
|  securityConfiguration defined in file [/Users/user/work/proj/target/classes/com/proj/config/SecurityConfiguration.class]
↑     ↓
|  userService defined in file [/Users/user/work/proj/target/classes/com/proj/service/UserService.class]
└─────┘
```

`UserService` does not inject `SecurityConfiguration`, so I am unsure how to get past this issue. Is there another way around this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I solved this by mixing [constructor and setter injection](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-collaborators) for the `SecurityConfiguration` class as such:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder;

    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    private UserRepository userRepository;

    private final TokenProvider tokenProvider;

    private final CorsFilter corsFilter;

    private UserService userService;

    public SecurityConfiguration(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder, UserDetailsService userDetailsService,
            TokenProvider tokenProvider, CorsFilter corsFilter, UserRepository userRepository) {

        this.authenticationManagerBuilder = authenticationManagerBuilder;
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.tokenProvider = tokenProvider;
        this.corsFilter = corsFilter;
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setUserService(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }
}
```

Once I do this I see the constructor be called with the right arguments, then the `UserService` be constructed and then injected into the setter for the `SecurityConfiguration` as I wanted it to be.